# How to set text of multiple codes in one text view

Tags: android

Please have a look at this code and at the bottom is the question. Thanks for your help

```
int i,fact=1;
String value = edtLCM.getText().toString();
       
for (i = Integer.parseInt(value); i >= 1; i--) {
    fact = fact * i;
    if (i > 1) {
        String one = i + " x ";
        System.out.print(i + " x ");
    } else {
        System.out.print(i);
        String two = String.valueOf(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(" = " + fact);
LCMResult.setText("");
```

I want to set the textview of all the 3 "System.out.println()" in one line. The desired result would be like this(if a user input 4 in the edtLCM): 4x3x2x1 = 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a StringBuilder to put the new strings together instead of using system out.

```
int i,fact=1;
String value = edtLCM.getText().toString();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // find a better name
       
for (i = Integer.parseInt(value); i >= 1; i--) {
    fact = fact * i;
    if (i > 1) {
        String one = i + " x ";
        // System.out.print(i + " x ");
        sb.append(i).append(" x ");
    } else {
        //System.out.print(i);
        sb.append(i);
        String two = String.valueOf(i);
    }
}
//System.out.println(" = " + fact);
sb.append(" = ").append(fact);
String result = sb.toString(); // will be 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24
LCMResult.setText("");
```